# How to remove escape characters (escaping unicode chars) from unicode string in Python2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

```
>>> test
u'"Hello," he\u200b said\u200f\u200e.\n\t"I\u200b am\u200b nine years old\xe2"'
>>> test2
'"Hello," he\\u200b said\\u200f\\u200e.\n\t"I\\u200b am\\u200b nine years old"'
>>> print test
"Hello," he said‏‎.
        "I am nine years oldâ"
>>> print test2
"Hello," he\u200b said\u200f\u200e.
        "I\u200b am\u200b nine years old"
```

So how would I convert from test2 to test (i.e. so that unicode characters are printed)? `.decode('utf-8')` doesn't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`unicode-escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) to decode `'\\u200b'` to `u'\u200b'`.

```
>>> test1 = u'"Hello," he\u200b said\u200f\u200e.\n\t"I\u200b am\u200b nine years old\xe2"'
>>> test2 = '"Hello," he\\u200b said\\u200f\\u200e.\n\t"I\\u200b am\\u200b nine years old"'
>>> test2.decode('unicode-escape')
u'"Hello," he\u200b said\u200f\u200e.\n\t"I\u200b am\u200b nine years old"'
>>> print test2.decode('unicode-escape')
"Hello," he​ said‏‎.
    "I​ am​ nine years old"
```

Note: But even with that, `test2` cannot be decoded to match exactly `test1` because there's a `u'\xe2'` in `test1` just before the closing quote (`"`).

```
>>> test1 == test2.decode('unicode-escape')
False
>>> test1.replace(u'\xe2', '') == test2.decode('unicode-escape')
True
```

Comment: Are escaped unicode characters are printed then? Given that the ones in the example are zero-space-spaces, I can't really tell. I assume u'\xe2' can't be printed because it's not unicode?

Comment: @kawakaze, `u'\xe2'` is `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX`. You can check using `unicodedata.name(u'\xe2')`